# Android Getting a int from a edit text?

Tags: java, android, string, android-edittext, int

I am trying to get an int from an edit text set to inputType="number" and then out put it ( i will do something with it later) i cant do it, this is the code i have which i have been told to try but it dose not work

```
Button go;
EditText num;
TextView OP, ST;
String OPS;
int oer;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initalize();
    go.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            int myNum = 0;

            OPS = num.getText().toString();

            try {
                myNum = Integer.parseInt(OPS);
            } catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
            }
            OP.setText(myNum);
        }
```

After i run it it force closes.
This Is the LOG CAT:

```
09-09 16:53:00.400: W/ResourceType(20145): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000008
09-09 16:53:00.400: D/AndroidRuntime(20145): Shutting down VM
09-09 16:53:00.400: W/dalvikvm(20145): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a411f8)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x8
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:248)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at com.Nutty.studios.randnumgen.free.RandomNumberGenActivity$1.onClick(RandomNumberGenActivity.java:42)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4575)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:556)
09-09 16:53:00.561: E/AndroidRuntime(20145):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

it works fine if i try to out put the string but not as an integer?

Comment: It helps if you describe how it fails. Is there unexpected output? An exception? What is the stack trace?

Comment: Use Log class to log and not System.out.println();

Comment: How do i do that and also i will put a log cat in he queestion

Comment: Log.e("This is a log my friend.");

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**1.** You will **never get an** `int` from EditText, `InputType` is provided **to provide you with the correct softKeyboard...**

**2.** You can **convert** the text from EditText in to integer using this..

`int i = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText().toString());`

moreover `setText` will expect you to provide it with a `String`.... so you need to do this...

`OP.setText(myNum+"");`

`toString()` only works with `Object` types, and as you have declared `myNum` as `int`, which is a **primitive type**.... you need to use `+ ""`

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH and also for the quick reply

Answer (score 2):

**`"inputType = number"`** does not mean that the input in the EditText would be in the form of an integer. It just implies the type of soft keyboard that would be shown to the user while entering the value and also the valid entries in the EditText,i.e. an EditText with `inputType=number` would take **only numbers** and nothing else,but these numbers would be **in string format** [`String number = "12345"`] and you would need to manually get the integer value  from
the string.

**Convert String input to integer :**

**`int myNum = Integer.valueOf(editText.getText().toString()).intValue();`**

---

Also, your output TextView can only have a string parameter in the `setText()` and you are trying to pass an integer. **`TextView.setText("STRING")`** is the format of showing the output in any TextView and if you are trying to display an integer in a TextView, you would need to convert it to a string first.

**Convert integer to String output :**    **`OP.setText(Integer.toString(myNum);`**

Comment: In an EditText with `inputType=number` and limited `maxLength` (4 for example), do we still have to catch exceptions to `Integer.parseInt`, or the output is guaranteed to be a correct integer value?

Answer (score 2):

OP.setText(myNum) is causing the crash.

This is due to the nature of setText(int value), where it will look up a string resource rather than set the literal value of the integer.

Instead you would need to do: 
`OP.setText(String.valueOf(myNum))`
Everything else is ok.

Comment: Also, the safest approach would be to do String.valueOf(myNum) in a try catch with a default value.